# IAM Role as a Principal

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

When I attempt to create this IAM Policy in Account B (111111111111) so that the role from Account A (2222222222222) can access a specific ECR repository, it errors stating the principal is invalid.

```
Unsupported Principal: The policy type IDENTITY_POLICY does not support the Principal element. Remove the Principal element.
```

This is the invalid policy, if I was to remove the principal role, I don't fully understand how I can achieve the same outcome.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [{
    "Sid": "Sid0",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {
      "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::2222222222222:role/role-name-1"
    },
    "Action": [
      "ecr:DescribeImages",
      "ecr:DescribeRepositories"
      "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
      "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
      "ecr:GetRepositoryPolicy",
      "ecr:ListImages",
      "ecr:BatchGetImage",
      "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken"
    ],
    "Resource": [
      "arn:aws:ecr:us-west-1:111111111111:repository/ecr-name-1"
    ]
    }]
}
```

Comment: How to [allow a secondary account to push or pull images in my Amazon ECR repo](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/secondary-account-access-ecr/) might be a helpful resource.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you use [identity-based policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies.html#policies_id-based) the `Principal` of the policy is **automatically** inferred once you attach the policy to IAM user or role. In that case, the given user/role becomes the  `Principal`. Thus you do not explicitly specify it.

In contrast, for [resource-based policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies.html#policies_id-based), such as S3 bucket policy, you have to specify the `Principal`. This is because these polices are **bound to a resource**, not to any IAM user or role. Thus you have to explicitly define `Principal` for them.

Comment: My issues are: 1) the resource I want to allow this access to is an ECR so I cannot attach this directly to a repository 2) the identity making the interaction is an EC2 (via EC2 Role) which is from a different account.

Answer (score 2):

What you seem to be doing is [IAM role chaining](https://aws.plainenglish.io/aws-iam-role-chaining-df41b1101068).

IAM policies cannot have principals. Only resource policies, such as S3 bucket policies, can. The principal in an IAM policy is always implicitly the identity that is making the API call that is being evaluated against the policy.

IAM roles have trust policies that define which conditions must be met to allow other principals to assume the role. You need to do two things:

1. the assuming identity must have permission to perform AssumeRole on the to-be-assumed role (and you do this in the IAM role's policy in account A)
2. the to-be-assumed role must allow the assuming identity to assume the role (and you do this in the trust policy in account B)

For more, see [How to use trust policies with IAM roles](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-use-trust-policies-with-iam-roles/).